# web application automatically changing to website in visual studio 2017

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-applications, visual-studio-2017

I have a existing  `web application` project so when I change something in that and once again opening the same project its changing automatically to website. I am using `visual studio 2017` and project is implemented in VS 2010.
If I opened second time the below warning message is coming.
[image]

Solution I have tried:

1)
I have opened Project_Name.csproj.vspscc file (*.vspscc) and changed below settings but still issue persist.

```
"ENLISTMENT_CHOICE" = "COMPULSORY" to "ENLISTMENT_CHOICE" = "NEVER"

"ORIGINAL_PROJECT_FILE_PATH" = "http://localhost/WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj" to "ORIGINAL_PROJECT_FILE_PATH" = ""
```

2) I have unto all the pending changes to the project and opened it again but still the issue persist.

Answer (score 0):

1. open the .sln file in a text editor.  Look for the following line:

> SccProjectEnlistmentChoice = 2

remove the line and save it and re-open the solution. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the replay , but still it is not working. it is still as web site only